# How to add custom Javascript and external src link to a Gravity Form?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I know we can inject custom script into a gravity form using this: http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/page/Gform_register_init_scripts

The example uses a jquery script. But is it possible to inject normal javascript code like below?

```
var addresses = document.getElementsByClassName('classAddress');
i = addresses.length;

while (i--) {
   var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(addresses[i]);
}
```

Also how can one add a external link to JS to a Gravity Form instance like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='...'></script>
```

Not sure where to do this in functions.php or a Gravity Form related php file

Answer (score 1):

Yeh, you can. This is how I did it (prepare for a nutty hacky but working contraption). It's a really ugly, nasty way of doing it but there was a time constraint so I apologize in advance since this is not the WordPress way of doing things.

I made a custom field, mycustomfield ,(which using css i made not visible on the form) and then i just filtered the field and in its place pulled in a php file containing 8 jquery files. So create an empty file called scriptjs.php, and you can put whatever you want in there and it will get pulled into the form and that's that.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='...'></script>
```

Add the code below to functions.php, change the 'plugins_url'  in the code to your theme folder or wherever you plan on hosting the scriptsjs.php file. Don't forget to make a custom field, or you can just filter another field that you are not using for example.

```
add_filter("gform_field_input", "mycustomfield_input", 10, 5);

function mycustomfield_input($input, $field, $value, $lead_id, $form_id){
    if($field["type"] == "mycustomfield"){
            $input_name = $form_id .'_' . $field["id"];
            $tabindex = GFCommon::get_tabindex();
            $css = isset( $field['cssClass'] ) ? $field['cssClass'] : '';
            $input='';
            if(!is_admin()){
                $input=file_get_contents(plugins_url('scriptjs.php', __FILE__));
            }
    }
    return $input;
}
```

Comment: Ok. Well thanks for answering. Just found an cleaner/easier way to do this: using wp_enqueue_script(...) http://planetozh.com/blog/2008/04/how-to-load-javascript-with-your-wordpress-plugin/. With this WP function it is good that one can simply add even an external url to link a JS source!

Comment: Also to add a custom jQuery & JS script one can use this filter: http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/page/Gform_register_init_scripts

Comment: Everything you say is correct, but either due to the version of Gravity Form the client uses or some other issues, I was unable to get it in there any other way. Its a brutal smash approach when all else fails. Also if you have a multi step form, try to get the JS to be there only in one of the steps using the methods you described.

Comment: Ah ok. Yea currently I have it working for just the form page. Yeah since I'm using multi step form I will try to find a way for loading the JS only on 1 step. Didn't think about this...I think the hooks from GF are handy but need to understand how they work to make such simple functionality work...Have you tried loading a JS code just for one of the steps?